# Repeating a setInterval

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently using a `setInterval` function in JavaScript for an HTML page. It has a button that allows me to start a countdown from 10 to 0 with a 1 second interval, and every time I press the button the countdown is supposed to reset. However, after the first button press the next countdown messes up the interval badly.

```js
var count;

function countdown() {
  count = 10;
  var repeat = setInterval(reduce, 1000);
}

function reduce() {
  if (count > 0) {
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = count;
    count--;
  } else {
    clearInterval(repeat);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page 4</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button style=" display: inline-block; " onclick="countdown()">Start Count Down</button>
  <div style=" display: inline-block;" id="number"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `repeat` is out of scope for `clearInterval`. Declare `repeat` outside the function.

Comment: Or just call `clearInterval(repeat);` before `count = 10;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a global variable `repeat` and reset if set when countdown is invoked.

```js
var count,
    repeat;

function countdown(){     
    count = 10;
    if (repeat) {
        clearInterval(repeat);
    }
    repeat = setInterval(reduce, 1000);     
}

function reduce() {
    if (count > 0) {
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = count;
        count--;
    } else {
        clearInterval(repeat);
    }
}
```

```html
<button style=" display: inline-block; " onclick ="countdown()" >Start Count Down</button>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="number"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is the `repeat` variable, it's defined and accessible only inside `countdown`.
You could just make it global as well, and then you'd have to clear previous intervals when clicking the button again

```
var count, repeat;

function countdown() {
    clearInterval(repeat);
    count = 10;
    repeat = setInterval(reduce, 1000);
}

function reduce() {
    if (count > 0) {
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = count;
        count--;
    } else {
        clearInterval(repeat);
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ccgwkz4c/)

Answer (score 0):

put your repeat outside so the function reduce can access  it

```
    var count;
    var repeat = null;
    function countdown(){

      count = 10;
      repeat = setInterval(reduce, 1000);


    }

    function reduce() {
      if(count > 0)
      {document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = count;
      count--;}
      else
      {clearInterval(repeat);}


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `this` to stop interval;

```
clearInterval(this)
```

```js
var count;

function countdown() {
  count = 10;
  var repeat = setInterval(reduce, 1000);
}

function reduce() {
  if (count > 0) {
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = count--;
  } else {
    clearInterval(this);
  }
}
```

```html
<button style=" display: inline-block; " onclick="countdown()">Start Count Down</button>
<div style=" display: inline-block;" id="number"></div>
```

This will solve your issue but will raise another issue. If you click multiple times, multiple events will be registered. For this, you should either disable button or define `repeat` in parent scope.

```js
var count, repeat;

function countdown() {
  count = 10;
  repeat = repeat || setInterval(reduce, 1000);
}

function reduce() {
  if (count > 0) {
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = count--;
  } else {
    clearInterval(this);
  }
}
```

```html
<button style=" display: inline-block; " onclick="countdown()">Start Count Down</button>
<div style=" display: inline-block;" id="number"></div>
```

You will notice a simple trick:

```
repeat = repeat || setInterval(reduce, 1000);
```

This will ensure multiple intervals are not registered.